# Can anyone explain me how this java code works?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Rand {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Random ran = new Random();
        int number = ran.nextInt(9) + 1;
        number *= 10000;
        number += ran.nextInt(10000);
        System.out.println("Random no:" + number);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you not understand about it?

Comment: Why didn't try yourself? Don't you have a compiler? Don't you have internet access? Since you can write this, last question is irrelevant.

Comment: i have all!! but i dont knw how this code works?? the logic in it??

Comment: Try reading the javadoc. [Random#nextInt(n: int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29), [arithmetic operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And what is so mysterious about it?

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Random ran = new Random();

    //Generate a digit between 0-8 +1
    int number = ran.nextInt(9) + 1;
    //Multiply with 10000
    number *= 10000;
    //Add a number between 0-9999
    number += ran.nextInt(10000);

    System.out.println("Random no:" + number);
}
```

You should gain some fundamental knowledge, before you ask here - or at least try to solve the problem by yourself.